# How to install Couchbase on ArchLinux

Tags: arch-linux, rpm, deb

Is it possible to install CouchBase in ArchLinux?
This database looks so promising, but they only provide `.deb`, `.rpm`, `windows`, and `mac` version.

http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/downloads

Comment: As it turns out, `.rpm`s and `.deb`s are actually just special tarballs. There's nothing to stop you from writing your own `PKGBUILD` and using those as source files if, for some reason, you would rather not use the source code.

Comment: yeah, I got an error when build it, `http://pastebin.com/6KheqK78` because of newer version of v8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pretty easy to build it from sources if you need it on your development machine: https://github.com/couchbase/manifest#building-with-repo

```
repo init -u git://github.com/couchbase/manifest.git -m rel-3.0.1.xml
repo sync
make
```

it will install server for you to `$PWD/install`

Answer (score 0):

I've made a tutorial to compile Couchbase version 3.0.1 for those who gets the same problem
http://kokizzu.blogspot.com/2014/11/how-to-install-couchbase-on-archlinux.html